# How to provide a unique stub for the same provider for each test case in Angular 2 testing with jasmine?

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner, angular5, angular-test

Lets say I have two test cases within the same describe block, that need to use the same service, but each of them have to be provided with different service stubs? The example below will provide the both test cases with serviceStub1 as expected, but I need to find a way to provide the second case with serviceStub2. I've spent quite a bit of time on that and I am lost so far. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
describe('Component: ComponentUnderTest', () => {

      const serviceStub1 = {
            method: () => value1;
      };

      const serviceStub2 = {
            method: () => value2;
      };

    beforeEach(() => {

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [ComponentUnderTest],
            providers: [
                {provide: Service, useValue: serviceStub1},
            ]
        });

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ComponentUnderTest);
    });

    //should be tested with serviceStub1
    it("should do something when provider method returns value 1");

    //should be tested with serviceStub2
    it("should do something when provider method returns value 2");
});
```

Comment: I am confused. Could you not provide a different describe for each test with it's own serviceStub? each describe would have it's beforeEach

Comment: yeah you could, but this example is very bare bones. for real test cases you would end up simply copy pasting lot's of code, so I am wondering if there is a a better way to do it.